# Return an exit code without killing caller's terminal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

I'm having a hard time getting the return value from a script. The script that is giving me trouble is ***`second.sh`*** below. But there's an interaction present with a script called ***`first.sh`***, and that interaction seems to be the source of the trouble.

The first script is a test script and drives the second script. It needs the second script to set a cross-compile environment (hence the reason for a leading dot). The first script then invokes ***`make`*** with various variables set, like ***`CXX`*** and ***`CXXFLAGS`***.

```
# first.sh

. ./second.sh arg1
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    make
    ...
fi

. ./second.sh arg2
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    make
    ...
fi

. ./second.sh arg3
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    make
    ...
fi
```

The second script is usually run stand-alone by the user, and it's quite involved because it's detecting platforms, architectures and other miscellaneous features. It sets various variables, like ***`CXX`*** and ***`CXXFLAGS`*** used by ***`make`*** in the first script.

```
# second.sh
...

# if success, return 0
exit 0
...

# if failure, return non-0
exit 1
```

The problem I am having is the call to ***`exit`*** in ***`second.sh`*** kills the terminal, so ***`first.sh`*** is stopped dead in its tracks. A similar problem occurs when the user runs it stand alone.

When I attempt to change the second script to:

```
# second.sh
...

# if success, return 0
return 0

# else for failure, return non-0
return 1
```

Then, from ***`first.sh`*** perspective, ***`second.sh`*** always fails, even with ***`return 0`***.

How do I add a return code that does not kill the terminal under Bash?

---

To date, I've been running *without* the first test script, so the second script does not need to return success/failure. But I'm trying to automate testing, so I really need to be able to get a return code

Comment: Because you dotted it in, it's exiting script 1. Perhaps organize script into functions ?

Comment: I've a question for you. Do you really need to source your script? It is not enough to execute them?

Answer (score 2):

One perhaps not ideal way is to do `alias exit=return`, which then makes the `second.sh` exits do script return instead, with the code as given. This of course doesn't cut through nesting of functions like `exit` does, but it should work well for top-level `exit` calls.

You might need to `unalias exit` eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The knot of the problem is that you are sourcing (`.`) the script and not simply executing them (`./script2.sh` or `/bin/bash script2.sh`).

If you really need to `source` them do it in a subshell `(. ./myscript2.sh args)`

If you can execute *normally* the scripts you can store in a variable the exit code that is automatically updated after each execution in `$?`.

```
./myscript2.sh arg1
FirstExitCode=$?
./myscript2.sh arg2
SecondExitCode=$?
 ...
```

Read more about source with `help .`

Answer (score 1):

Based on Hastur's answer about sourcing, this seems to be what I need in `second.sh` to return a status without killing the terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...

# if success, return 0
[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] && exit 0 || return 0

# else for failure, return non-0
[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] && exit 1 || return 1
```